# Does this problem make sense? "Give an example of a set $F\subset C([0,1])$ which is pointwise bounded but not bounded"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I think that the professor might mean pointwise bounded but not *uniformly* bounded? Or is there a way that it makes sense to think of $F$ being bounded? $C([0,1])$ refers to the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Boundedness makes sense only with respect to a norm (or at least metric). Of course *pointwise* means that we investigate for $x\in[0,1]$ the set $\{f(x)\mid f\in F\}\subseteq \mathbb R$; as this is a subset of $\mathbb R$, boundedness with respect to $|\cdot|$ is implied.
Boundedness of $F$ itself must refer to a metric on $C([0,1])$ and one may assume indeed that $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ is implied. So, yes, it would be less ambiguous to explicitly speak of *uniform* boundedness.

As for the problem itself: We would like to use $f(x)=\frac1x$, but of course cannot. But how can we *almost* use it?

Comment: So as far as I understand, we need *one* function $\phi\in C([0,1])$ such that for every $f\in F$, $|f(x)|<\phi(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. But if $\phi\in C([0,1])$ then $\phi$ is bounded, say by $M$, so doesn't this imply that each $f\in F$ is bounded by $M$, and so $F$ is uniformly bounded? Or does $\phi$ not need to be in $C([0,1[)$?